# Why are some styles not working when using a Svelte component rendered by Go?

Tags: css, svelte, shadow-dom

I'm experimenting with using Svelte (not SvelteKit) in a Golang application. But I've hit a stumbling block with the CSS not being rendered correctly on the Svelte component. It's pulling in some of the styles from pico.css, but missing others.

I've got the code down to:

```html
// templates/mainpage.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@picocss/pico@1/css/pico.min.css">
    <script defer src='/public/build/bundle.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <main class="container">
        <h1>H1 from the HTML template</h1>
        <button>Button</button>
        <hr />
        <my-app/>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
// src/App.svelte
<script>
</script>

<svelte:options tag="my-app" />
<h1>H1 from the Svelte component</h1>
<button>Button</button>

<style>
</style>
```

which generates the following page:

[image: screenshot of the application]

The HTML template renders correctly, while the Svelte component has picked up on the H1 font-family and font-size correctly but not got the H1 color. And none of the Button styles are applied.

I've gone down a rabbit hole with Shadow Doms and CSS variables, but I'm no front-end expert and I'm stumped as to why only partial styles are being applied.

Any pointers on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That probably is the shadow DOM, you can do this to disable it:

```html
<svelte:options shadow="none" ...>
```

Note that this prevents the component from having slots ([docs](https://svelte.dev/docs/custom-elements-api)).

Comment: That's done it! I would never have found that, thank you!

I had to change the line to `<svelte:options customElement={{ tag: "my-app", shadow: 'none' }} />`, it didn't like having shadow as an attribute.